# Cloning Repository from Github not downloading all folders and files as expected

Tags: linux, git, macos, github, terminal

Hello I am working on a project with a fellow developer that is running a Linux OS and I am running mac OS.

I am cloning his repository to my desktop from GitHub and I am not getting all of the folders and files that he has on the Repository .

they are not ". hidden " folders. `ls -a` would show them.

Ive done a `git reset --hard`  and `git log` to be sure I have the most recent commit (which I do)

I am all up to date with every but I am still missing a couple folders . I cant find anything online I am just baffled.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've ran into a similar issue because of the way OSX and linux differ in their handling of case sensitivity. Is this related to that? If not, could you describe which (kinds of) files are missing?

Comment: Yes exactly It is case sensitivity  "actions"->"Actions"

Comment: Ok, I solved it using this: https://coderwall.com/p/mgi8ja/case-sensitive-git-in-mac-os-x-like-a-pro but that requires a repartition

Comment: That is awesome, thank you so much. I was so baffled and the other engineer thought I didn't know simple git commands haha.